For loop nested w/ if statement for deleting users
I'm new to bash / scripting (at least to this degree). I keep getting the error that the command doesn't exist on line 16 (if [$i -eq 0]), this is for cleaning up a bunch of users i create while learning how to write bash scripts (so apologies if its basic, but that's the level I'm at!)
`    #!/bin/bash
 # clear out users
 declare -a users=(
 [0]=anna
 [1]=linda
 [2]=bill
 [3]=audrey
 [4]=lisa
 [5]=ben
 )

 for i in ${users[@]}
 do
getent passwd ${users[$i]}
if [$i -eq True]
then
userdel -r ${users[$i]}
else
echo "user doesn't exist"
fi
done`

The idea is the for loop iterates through the array, uses the getent passwd $i if it comes back as true / 0 it runs the userdel -r if it doesnt exist it just prints out "user doesnt exist". I'll be doing the same for folders & groups, but I'll figure that out myself

You're missing a space after the [

As mentioned in  the [tag:bash] tag you have included, please learn to check your code at https://shellcheck.net before posting. Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or similar) as the first line. If you still have problems, post the shellcheck corrected code with a note that you have used it. Good luck

There are several other confusions here; for i in ${users[@]} iterates over the array entries (e.g. "anna", "linda", etc), not indexes (0, 1, 2, ...), so ${users[$i]} doesn't do what you want; you want just plain "$i".  Also, [ $i -eq True ] which expands to e.g. [ anna -eq True ], doesn't make any sense at all since neither anna nor True is a number (and True isn't even a thing in bash). What you really want here is if getent passwd "$i" (see "Bash conditional based on exit code of command").

I'd recommend you don't write a script to delete users or do anything else destructive and potentially disastrous until you're much more familiar with Unix/shell.

Why are you using an associative array? Indexed array start with index 0 anyway.
